# how to provide a steady voltage, in case of source voltage drop due to heavy consumers in the circuit

Tags: arduino, voltage, voltage-regulator

I am designing an arduino circuit in which the power source is a battery connected to some heavy current consumers, these consumers are intended to work for short time and infrequently, my question is how to provide my arduino with a steady voltage, I am thinking of using capacitors to serve the arduino while these heavy consumers are working but I am not sure how

Comment: We need to see what you have so far.

Comment: Dude, you can use small UPS but it will be expensive for a DIY project.

Comment: It's a simple lock circuit (arduino, keypad and an lcd) in my car powered by the car battery but during starting , voltage drops to supply the starter motor, which causes noise and affects the lcd display

Comment: Noise is a *very* different thing to fix than a voltage drop.

Comment: when the voltage on the lcd change(in my case drops until the motor is started), it display strange charters, excuse me if I used a wrong terminology

Comment: The length of time of the voltage sag is very important, as it will determine whether you can get a realistic capacitor value to cover it.

Comment: @gbarry as i mentioned, the problem only happens during starting the car's engine, i think it won't exceed 2 sec under normal conditions

Comment: How are you powering the arduino now? I mean, that can't be directly powered with the 12+V car battery.

Comment: @VladimirCravero i am using a volt-regulator

Comment: And can you please tell us which voltage regulator you are currently using?

Comment: I am using a L7805cv

Comment: show us a circuit

Comment: So you are using a 7805 to power both the arduino and the LCD? There is nothing else connected? Is the arduino only driving the LCD and receiving power through the 7805? If yes, your problems are probably due to noise. Get a voltmeter and see if the output of the 7805 drops when you you turn the ignition key and the bogus characters appear on the LCD. If this is the case, add a capacitor after the 7805. Play around with a few. If this is not the case, then noise is your problem. Try wrapping the whole thing, board and wires, with some thick (heavy duty) aluminium foil and see if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the +ve of the power source to the anode of a diode.
Connect the cathode of the diode to the +ve of an electrolytic capacitor (100 uF and up).
Connect the -ve of the capacitor to the -ve of the power source.

Connect the VCC of your circuit to the +ve of the capacitor.
Connect the GND of your circuit to the -ve of the capacitor.

The diode will prevent the capacitor from discharging into the "heavy current consumers" when they turn on momentarily and will prevent the dip on VCC.

If the dip is too much and is critical for the functioning of the "heavy current consumers", you need a capacitor between the +ve and -ve of the power source as well.